# Creating Variable by Using Criteria From Multiple Columns (PANDAS)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a column named HouseholdSize and a column named Independent. I want to create a variable that is equal to 1 if HouseholdSize equals 1 and Independent does not equal 1. My current code looks like this:

```
        df["HH1flag"] = df.where((df.HouseholdSize ==1) & (df.Independent != 1).notnull().astype(int))
            HH1flag = df[df.HH1flag == 1]
            pd.DataFrame(HH1flag, columns=["LocIdent","HouseholdSize","Independent"]).to_csv(Targcsv, mode='ab')
```

I get the following error: 
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'all'

Edit: With some help from EdChum, I am adding a bit more information to this question. A simplified version of my revised code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *
import csv

FileName='HouseholdSizeTest.xlsx'
data=pd.read_excel(FileName,'Sheet1')
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
Targcsv=('target.csv')

HH1Text= [['Table C.1 HouseholdSize Check 1']]
with open(Targcsv,'ab') as f:
    titles=csv.writer(f)
    titles.writerow([])
    titles.writerows(HH1Text)
    titles.writerow([])

df["HH1flag"] = df[(df.HouseholdSize ==1) & (df.Independent != 1)].notnull().astype(int)
HH1flag = df[df.HH1flag == 1]
pd.DataFrame(HH1flag, columns=["LocIdent","HouseholdSize","Independent"]).to_csv(Targcsv, mode='ab')
```

I get a new error, for that same line. The error is ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1. I am struggling to put the data into this edit formatted correctly, but imagine three cases. the first with Independent=1 and HouseholdSize=1, the second with Independent=0 and HouseholdSize=3, and the third with Independent=47 and HouseholdSize=1. For the third case, HH1flag should be equal to 1.

Comment: Are you doing this correctly? You've not stated which line throws the error, I'm assuming it's the first line as it looks weird to me, are you wanting this instead: `df["HH1flag"] = df.where((df.HouseholdSize ==1) & (df.Independent != 1)).notnull().astype(int)`?

Comment: Hi EdChum. Sorry for not specifying, it is the first line that throws the error.  I tried pasting the code you have in your comment into my code, and I got the same error. Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Comment: Can you post raw input data and code to create the df so we can reproduce your error thanks

Comment: I think you cannot pass such conditions to `df.where` try this: `df[(df.HouseholdSize ==1) & (df.Independent != 1)].notnull().astype(int)` not sure if this is the result you want though

Comment: So it looks like you are just trying to assign some indicator value if your conditions are met correct? try this:` np.where((df.HouseholdSize ==1) & (df.Independent != 1), 1, 0)` you can expand the conditions if this doesn't quite capture what you want

Comment: EdChum that worked! Thank you again for all of your help. I feel like you have answered at least one of my questions in the past, and you always do so so quickly and helpfully! If you "answer" the question I can mark it as answered, otherwise, just know that I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an indicator column then you can use `np.where`:

```
df["HH1flag"] = np.where((df.HouseholdSize ==1) & (df.Independent != 1), 1, 0)
```

So this uses the passed in condition and if true returns 1, if false it returns 0.

The reason my first suggestion didn't work was because this returns a series with multiple column values which is not what you wanted.

When you did `df.where` it didn't like trying to cast your series and raised an `AttributeError`:

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'all'

I don't know why it does this, there is nothing special about your data as I was was able to reproduce this with a simple df consisting of just ints.

Comment: Hi EdChum,

Quick question. I have tried to use an "or" statement with three columns with the code looking like this: df["NCP2flag"] = np.where((df.NCPFlag ==1) & ((df.NCPIncReported == -999) or (df.NCPPCReported == -999)), 1, 0)

I get an error saying: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). Is there a way to rewrite the line to circumvent this? I know this is getting really specific at this point, but I really appreciate all your help!

Comment: You can't use `and`, `or` when you are comparing arrays hence the error you have to use the bitwise operators so: `df["NCP2flag"] = np.where((df.NCPFlag ==1) & ((df.NCPIncReported == -999) | (df.NCPPCReported == -999)), 1, 0) `